# How can i add bootstrap 4 to angular 5 with components

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular5

How can I easily add bootstrap 4 to angular 5 with components? I am new in angular 5 and also in Bootstrap 4. I get an answer to this question but I am confused because to worry about my project efficiency.

Please guide or refer me someone best article.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not. Check this.
The [easy way to add bootstrap 4 to angular 5 with components.](https://gethybridapp.com/easy-way-add-bootstrap-4-angular-5-components/)

Answer (score 1):

You may like ngx-bootstrap. The library includes components created in angular using bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4
 https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/&hl=en-IN

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav, Actually I have a theme based on Bootstrap 4. That's why I needed Bootstrap 4 solution.

Comment: @Akash it is having bootstrap 4 as well https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started